# Button on Accordion Header redirecting angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, accordion

I'm getting a peculiar problem. I have a nested accordion and I need a button like Edit on every accordion. When the button is clicked, I need to call a different function. What I'm doing is on click of the edit button I'm trying to use `$event.stopPropagation()` which will stop accordion functionality.  But this isn't happening when I pass `$event.stopPropagation()`. It is redirecting to some other URL.

I'm posting some of my huge code. If any further info is required please comment.

**HTML**

```
<accordion-heading>
    {{course.className}}
    <button type="button" 
      ng-show="course.classId!=$scope.null" 
      class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-sm" 
      ng-click="editCourse(course,$event)">
         Edit Course 
    </button>
</accordion-heading>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.editCourse = function(course, ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    course.courseEditPermission = true;
}
```

**app.js**

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html',
            hideMenus: true
        })

        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/xyz'
        });
}])
```

I don't know why it is redirecting but in my JS I provided routes, so I think `event.stopPropagation` is getting some anonymous URL, so it is redirecting to "/xyz" as I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event.preventDefault() handler like this:

```
$scope.editCourse = function(course, ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     ev.stopPropagation();
     course.courseEditPermission = true;
}
```